# Docker container unhealthy but no error in the logs

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow

I am using the official `docker-compose` [file](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.2/docker-compose.yaml) of `airflow` to spin it up.

Some of my containers seem unhealthy:

```
34d8698d67e7   apache/airflow:2.0.2   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   31 minutes ago   Up 28 minutes (unhealthy)   0.0.0.0:5555->5555/tcp, :::5555->5555/tcp, 8080/tcp   airflow_flower_1
a291cf238b9f   apache/airflow:2.0.2   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   31 minutes ago   Up 29 minutes               8080/tcp                                              airflow_airflow-init_1
fdb20e9152f3   apache/airflow:2.0.2   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   31 minutes ago   Up 29 minutes (unhealthy)   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp             airflow_airflow-webserver_1
abf5a16aa846   apache/airflow:2.0.2   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   31 minutes ago   Up 29 minutes               8080/tcp                                              airflow_airflow-worker_1
f6dc352f407b   apache/airflow:2.0.2   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   31 minutes ago   Up 28 minutes               8080/tcp                                              airflow_airflow-scheduler_1
12dfc71e518f   redis:latest           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   31 minutes ago   Up 29 minutes (healthy)     0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp, :::6379->6379/tcp             airflow_redis_1
```

However the logs of one of them for example do not seem very informative.

```
# docker logs -f fdb20e9152f3
WARNING! You should run the image with GID (Group ID) set to 0
         even if you use 'airflow' user (UID=50000)
 You started the image with UID=50000 and GID=50000
 This is to make sure you can run the image with an arbitrary UID in the future.
 See more about it in the Airflow's docker image documentation
     http://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/entrypoint
BACKEND=postgresql+psycopg2
DB_HOST=my-db-endpoint
DB_PORT=5432
WARNING! You should run the image with GID (Group ID) set to 0
         even if you use 'airflow' user (UID=50000)
 You started the image with UID=50000 and GID=50000
 This is to make sure you can run the image with an arbitrary UID in the future.
 See more about it in the Airflow's docker image documentation
     http://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/entrypoint
BACKEND=postgresql+psycopg2
DB_HOST=my-db-endpoint
DB_PORT=5432
```

Regardless of any `airflow` - specific issues, how can I check `docker` - wise what's going on?

Docker seems to be aware of a couple of containers not being healty.

**edit**: both failing containers have the `healtcheck` condition

```
healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:5555/"]
```

and

```
healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/"]
```

that seems to be failing by looking into their `inspect` output

```
 Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused
```

but I cannot pinpoint what is causing the failure.

**edit**: I have tried following the instructions to start the `init` service first as well

```
# docker-compose up airflow-init
Starting airflow_redis_1 ... done
Starting airflow_airflow-init_1 ... done
Attaching to airflow_airflow-init_1
airflow-init_1       | BACKEND=postgresql+psycopg2
airflow-init_1       | DB_HOST=my-db-endpoint
airflow-init_1       | DB_PORT=5432
```

but it never exits, it prints the above message and that's it...

Comment: Did you execute `docker-compose up airflow-init` ?

Comment: It is one of the services, it runs with just `docker-compose up`, no?

Comment: The most weird part (to start with) is the fact that the only thing I see in my logs is the message I am printing in my question

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the docs?  https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html#docker-compose-yaml

Comment: yes, check my new edit on the question

Comment: If the curl request to `http://localhost:8080`  is failing then there may be a firewall or other networking issue preventing access to the port. Are you able to view the airflow webserver GUI in a browser?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into similar issue and it was docker volume causing the issue. As I was running lots of containers on my mac, there wasn;t enough disk space. I managed to fixed this issue my pruning the docker volume.

> docker volume prune

This will remove any unused volume on your mac book. Before running this command please check if you got any useful data.

Answer (score 0):

For docker-compose, from the entrypoint, the default value of group id is 0.

```
"${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:${AIRFLOW_GID:-0}"
```

Edit your docker-compose.yaml file or ad ass env.sh file in your Airflow project repository.

Answer (score 0):

It does seems to be an error due to less memory allocated to docker for running this image, try to increase the resources available to docker and see the magic

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issue and the `healthcheck`s were "causing" this. I was running them using default container's user.

Just to give a try, I changed the healthckeck command to start using `airflow` user instead, as follow:

`$ runuser -u airflow -- <healthckeck command>`

And it solved. I'm gonna change the user whom runs `docker compose up` to `airflow` from now on.